# What is the difference between PRECISION LENGTH`?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm reading the output of the `exec sp_columns` command and there are 2 columns I can't understand `PRECISION` and `LENGTH`

I just created the following table

If I'm not mistaken, the `quantity` column is a numeric `INTENGER` data type, that is, this column can store a number between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`

This information is correct right?

but if i execute

```sql
exec sp_columns Books;
```

`Precision`: I think it is the number of characters that the column allows, that is, a maximum of 10 characters between -2.1m and +2.1m

but I can't figure out why the `LENGTH` column says 4.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Books
(
    title VARCHAR(10), -- Maximum length up to 10 characters example 'ABCDFGHIJK'
    author VARCHAR(10),-- Maximum length up to 10 characters example 'ABCDFGHIJK'
    quantity INTEGER   -- ?
);
exec sp_columns Books;

INSERT INTO Prueba.dbo.Books
    (title,author,quantity)
VALUES
    ('Example A', 'A', 1),
    ('Example B', 'B', 12),
    ('Example C', 'C', 123),
    ('Example D', 'D', 123467890),
    ('Example E', 'E', 1234678901);
```

[image]

Comment: An `int` is 4 bytes is size.

Comment: :O @Larnu aaa that's a `size in bytes`! now this makes more sense to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `LENGTH` represents it defined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> | Column name | Data type | Dscription |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | LENGTH | int | Transfer size of the data.<sup>1</sup> |
>
> <sup>1</sup> For more information, see the Microsoft ODBC documentation<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>**The documentation does not contain a link to which Microsoft ODBC documentation they mean specifically, so the omission is not mine*</sup>

An [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is 4 bytes in size, and hence the column has a `LENGTH` of `4` defined in `sys.sp_columns`.